# Android map view onTap not working with no item pinned

Tags: android, android-mapview

I got the same problem of [Android onTap mapView method not working after removing all points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902286/android-ontap-mapview-method-not-working-after-removing-all-points)

When the map have more than one item, it works just fine. However, when i clear or remove all the pin items, i can't add any item. I read my log and figure out that when there are no item, the ontap method don't even being called. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the Overlay item is also removed when you remove all the pins , that is the reason onTap() is not working.

Try to create a list of overlay objects of only pin items and remove only the list of overlay of pins. This will work.